# how to forward RestFull request to another WL server inside the Cluster?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cluster-computing, weblogic12c

I have application running on WebLogic cluster. The application contains processing of the RestFull requests. 
There are the cases when only specific server (which one discovered during the request processing) can treat the request, so I have to forward this request to another server within the cluster.

What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/cluster/overview.html):

> A WebLogic Server cluster consists of multiple WebLogic Server server
>   instances running simultaneously and working together to provide
>   increased scalability and reliability. A cluster appears to clients to
>   be a single WebLogic Server instance.

So what you say doesn't make much sense. Every server in the cluster is supposed to do the very same thing. If there is a server that does something different, then it means that server is not really part of the cluster.

If you are in such a situation where only one of those servers have access to a resource (e.g. a physical printer), I'd suggest to create a new service which manages that resource, and let the cluster call that service instead of manually messing with the cluster's behaviour.